# Program returns none instead of value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started to learn python. I wrote a code to find molarity of CaCO3 soln. But the program always returns none.

```
#Program to find Molarity of CaCO3 soln.

w = int(input("Enter the weight of CaCO3 : "))
v = int(input("Volume of solution :" )) 


def molarity():
    molarity = ( w / 100) * (1000 / v)


print("the molarity is")
M = molarity()
print(M)
```

Comment: Your function needs a `return` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `molarity()` does not return a value so nothing happens when you call `M = molarity()`. The easiest and most straightforward solution is just to make sure your function returns its value:

```
def molarity():
    molarity = ( w / 100) * (1000 / v)
    return molarity
```

But if your program becomes more complex, you may also want to pass `w` and `v` as arguments to avoid conflicts.

```
def molarity(w, v):
    molarity = ( w / 100) * (1000 / v)
    return molarity
```

Then call it with `M = molarity(w, v)`